# how to get avg() size by day using two decimal places

Tags: sql-server

does this simple query result in grouping the attachments by day and giving me the total number of daily attachments as well as the average size?

the only table i am querying is attachmentdetail (email attachments)

```
[attachmentdetail]
    AttachmentId     int
    Name             varchar
    Size             int
    IsInline     bit
    InsertedDatetime datetime

select 
    count(*) as [Tally], 
    avg( cast(size as decimal)/1024/1024) as avgSize,
    DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, InsertedDatetime), 0) As [date_only]  
from attachmentdetail 
where isinline <>1
group by DateAdd(dd, DateDiff(dd, 0, InsertedDatetime), 0)
order by [date_only] desc
```

also how to i keep the values i get from my avg() to 2 decimal places?

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify precision and scale when casting to a decimal, and perform that cast *last*. [This blog post explains why you never want to leave out the size declaration for `char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), but similar arguments hold for decimal and a few other numeric types, too.

Also, on 2008+, `CONVERT(DATE` is a slightly more efficient (and easier to read) method of stripping time (see [this post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) and [this follow-up](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time)).

Here is how I would write your query:

```
SELECT
  [date_only] = CONVERT(DATE, InsertedDateTime),
  [Tally] = COUNT(*),
  avgSize = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2), AVG(size/1024.0/1024))
FROM dbo.attachmentdetail 
WHERE isinline <> 1
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, InsertedDateTime)
ORDER BY [date_only] DESC;
```

(Also, use [schema prefixes](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix) and [statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons). Always.)

Comment: still im not getting two decimal places with this code. i changed the sql to fix this: SELECT
  [date_only] = CONVERT(DATE, InsertedDateTime)
  ,[Tally] = COUNT(*)
  ,avgSize = CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),AVG(  size/1024.0/1024) )
  ,[daily MB gorwth] = COUNT(*) * CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),AVG(  size/1024.0/1024) )
FROM dbo.attachmentdetail 
WHERE isinline <> 1
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, InsertedDateTime)
ORDER BY [date_only] DESC;

Comment: @kacalapy you're right, I said to perform the cast last, and then I didn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only two decimal places in the average, you can CAST to a DECIMAL type limting the precision, like this:

```
CAST( avg( cast(size as decimal)/1024/1024) AS DECIMAL(6,2)) as avgSize
```

Looks like you're casting "size" to decimal just to get the math to work as decimal instead of integers, where you might round too much. It doesn't matter much, but I prefer to do that by specifying a decimal constant because I think it's easier to read. I'd re-write that column like this:

```
CAST( AVG( size / 1024.0 / 1024.0 ) AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS avgSize
```

If you're using a recent version of SQL Server, you might have a simpler way to create your date_only column, as well. You can just cast the DATETIME value to a DATE type, which doesn't include any time information:

```
CAST( InsertedDateTime AS DATE ) AS [date_only]
```

Other than that, I think your query does what you say you expect.

Comment: thanks, i started with the cast to decimal to avoid an overrun of the integer datatype of the size field... my math was failing.